# Set ‘Artist’ name in iTunes Connect on registration?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

This question isn't really a programming question, so it doesn't exactly belong on Stack Overflow, so I apologise for that in advance, but there seem to be many questions like this round here, as there are many iPhone devs around here...

---

Is there anyone who has recently (like within the last 3 months) registered an ***Individual*** Apple Developer account? When you first logged into iTunes Connect, did it provide you with the opportunity to set the artist or ‘company’ name that appears above your app in the store (in search results, etc.), that isn't your legal name?

---

### EDIT

Previously with an individual account, your legal name appeared as the seller, however, you could set any name you wished to appear as the company name, but you could not change it afterwards. However, as **corban** said below, it is now apparently not possible to set a company name for an individual account, so if you want a company name, you will have to register a company account (and do all the related legal crap).

Comment: Yes. Did it 3 times for customers lately. Not when you log in though, when you create your first app.

Comment: Why the sudden downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even with an individual account you are allowed to set a company/artist name when you create your first app in itunesconnect. This can be different from your legal name.

The legal name (with which you registered as a developer) comes up as the "Seller" of the app (below the app icon, in small print, in iTunes) whereas the artist/developer name is the name you enter in iTunesconnect and what shows up on the top in iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know. I just emailed Apple lately wanting to change my artist name, but they refused, so I'm considering registering a new account, and just wanted to know if I'll be able to set it then (what with all their policy changes requiring DUNS numbers and all that crap).

Comment: HTH. DUNS number is only needed if you register as a company, not as an individual.

Comment: I know about that. It was just so painful to transfer to a company account that I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed the possibility to add a company/artist name for an individual account. There are some discussions in the apple forums about that. I hope that there will be a possibility to add one.

Comment: Luckily, I recently (within the last month), created a new individual dev account and set a company name. So I'm safe for now :)